# Делигирование JavaScript. Получить значение потомка родителя

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

По клику на кнопку нужно выводить с помощью `alert` текст который в `h2` теге.  Выводить текст с тега `h2` блока в котором был клик e не выходит. Я пробовал обращаться к `parent` элементу, а от него к `child`. Но вывести получается только значение `h2` первого блока:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];

table.onclick = function(event) {

  var target = event.target;
  while (target != this) {
    if (target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
      alert(title.innerHTML);
      //alert ????  Тут с кодом проблемы
      return;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="table">
  <li>
    <h2>test-title-first</h2>
    <p>loremloremlorem</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>test-title-second</h2>
    <p>loremloremlorem</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>test-title-third</h2>
    <p>loremloremlorem</p>
    <button>buy</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Пример на стороннем редакторе: [jsfiddle-ayda3f2f](https://jsfiddle.net/dedn/ayda3f2f/)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ответ DimenSi это то что я хотел реализовать. Спасибо за ссылку на гуд туториал.

Comment: Вопросу более 5ти лет. Хочу сказать спасибо и тому кто задал, и тем кто ответил! Я только учусь, ковырял корзину 3 дня. и этим способом нашел как за 4 строки повесить "Добавить в корзину" на все товары!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накидываем onclick на table, чекам событие на нужный элемент, от него ищем родителя через closest(), потом у родителя через querySelector().

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');

table.onclick = function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  
  if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON') { 
   let title = target.closest('li').querySelector('h2').textContent;
    console.log(title);
}
}
```

```html
<ul id="table">
            <li>
                <h2>test-title-first</h2>
                <p>loremloremlorem</p>
                <button>buy</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>test-title-second</h2>
        <p>loremloremlorem</p>
                <button>buy</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>test-title-third</h2>
        <p>loremloremlorem</p>
                <button>buy</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: А если список три мили в длину? Вопрос о делегировании, вообще-то.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте весьма хорошую статью с основами: [тык](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

```js
// Ищем таблицу и вешаем слушатель клика
document.querySelector('#table').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let target = e.target;
  
  // Если нода - это кнопка (проверки должны быть сложнее, читайте по ссылке выше)
  if(target.nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
    // То запускаем обработку
    handler(target);
  }
});

function handler(button){
  // Ищем предка кнопки (li), у него берём первого потомка (h2) и оттуда текст
  // Этот код крепко привязан к разметке, лучше использовать методы closest и querySelector
  console.info(button.parentNode.children[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul id="table">
    <li>
        <h2>test-title-first</h2>
        <p>loremloremlorem</p>
        <button>buy</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>test-title-second</h2>
<p>loremloremlorem</p>
        <button>buy</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>test-title-third</h2>
<p>loremloremlorem</p>
        <button>buy</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```